# sed to match pattern between matching curly braces

Tags: sed, osx, regular-expression, escape-characters

From a pattern such as

```
[string 1]{string 2}
```

I want to extract `string 2`, the string between the *last* pair of *matching* curly braces -- that is delete `[string 1]` and the open `{` and close `}`.  My attempt below breaks when there is a additional `[`, `]` pairs in either `string 1` or `string 2`.

### Desired Output:

The desired output from the script below begins with `foo` and ends with a `digit`:

```
foo bar 1
foo bar 2
foo[3]{xyz} bar 3
foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 4
foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 5
foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 6
foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 7
foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 8'
foo $sq[abc]{xyz}$ bar 9'
foo $sq[abc]{xyz}$ bar 10'
```

### Assumptions:

- Parameter to `RemoveInitialSquareBraces` *always* begins with a `[` and ends with a `}`.
- The opening `[` for `string 1` *will* have a matching `]` at the point where the opening `{` begins for `string 2`.

### Platform:

- MacOS 10.9.5

### Script

```
#!/bin/bash

function RemoveInitialSquareBraces {
    #EXTRACTED_TEXT="$(\
    #      echo "$1" \
    #    | sed 's/^\[.*\]//'              \
    #    | sed 's/{//'                    \
    #    | sed 's/}$//'                   \
    #    )"
    EXTRACTED_TEXT="$(\
          echo "$1" \
        | sed 's/.*[^0-9]\]{\(.*\)}/\1/' \
        )"
        
    echo "${EXTRACTED_TEXT}"
}

RemoveInitialSquareBraces '[]{foo bar 1}'
RemoveInitialSquareBraces '[abc]{foo bar 2}'
RemoveInitialSquareBraces '[]{foo[3]{xyz} bar 3}'
RemoveInitialSquareBraces '[]{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 4}'
RemoveInitialSquareBraces '[goo{w}]{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 5}'
RemoveInitialSquareBraces '[goo[3]{w}]{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 6}'
RemoveInitialSquareBraces '[goo[3]{w} hoo[3]{5}]{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 7}'
RemoveInitialSquareBraces '[goo[3]{w} hoo[3]{5}]{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 8}'
RemoveInitialSquareBraces '[goo[3]{w} hoo[xyz]{5}]{foo $sq[abc]{xyz}$ bar 9}'
RemoveInitialSquareBraces '[goo[3]{w} hoo[xyz]{uvw}]{foo $sq[abc]{xyz}$ bar 10}'

exit 0
```

Comment: Does it need to be `sed` or are you open to other tools? If so, do you have `perl` installed?

Comment: @terdon: Yes I do have perl installed, but this is a piece of a larger bash script, so would prefer a `sed` solution. But if it turns out too difficult to do with `sed` ten I'll consider alternate solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to above input examples the script can be:

```
sed s/[^\"\']*[^0-9]\]{\(.*\)}/\1/ <<\END
"[]{foo bar 1}"
"[abc]{foo bar 2}"
"[]{foo[3]{xyz} bar 3}"
"[]{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 4}"
"[goo{w}]{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 5}"
"[goo[3]{w}]{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 6}"
"[goo[3]{w} hoo[3]{5}]{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 7}"
END
```

produces

```
"foo bar 1"
"foo bar 2"
"foo[3]{xyz} bar 3"
"foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 4"
"foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 5"
"foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 6"
"foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 7"
```

Other thing is your function which can be simplified:

```
function RemoveInitialSquareBraces {
    printf '%s\n' "$@" |
    sed ...
}
```

thus it will accept many argument(s).

**Update**: for more general case you can do the task in two steps:

```
sed -e "
s/\[.*\[.*\][^[]*\]/[]/  #remove square brackets inside square brackets
s/\[[^]]*\]{\(.*\)\}/\1/ #lazy strip square brackets and curle brackets
"
```

**Addition**: you can use perl-**grep**(GNU grep with perl extention):

```
grep -Po '\[([^][]*\[\w+\][^][]*)*\]{\K.*(?=})'
```

or sed with same regexp:

```
sed 's/\[\([^][]*\(\[\w\+\][^][]*\)*\)*\]{\(.*\)}/\3/'
```

Comment: It seems I need to use single quotes not double quotes in the script. Then things do work for the given test cases, but an explanation of `.*[^0-9]\]` would be helpful.

Comment: `.*[^0-9]\]` mean `any symbol(s) till the non-digit char with square bracket after it`

Comment: So, does that mean that this relies on there begin _only_ digits within the square braces? Also, your output has stripped off the `$sq` before the `[3]`.

Comment: Have updated test case to include non-digits within square brackets -- apologies for not considering that case before.

Comment: `$sq` was stripped becouse variable expansion (due to double-quotes)

Comment: Pasting you `sed` code as `sed 's/[^\"\']*[^0-9]\]{\(.*\)}/\1/'` into my bash script yields `unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'` and `syntax error: unexpected end of file`.  Also, note the two new test cases in the question.

Comment: @PeterGrill note that he didn't enclose the `sed` command in quotes. You added `sed '...'` and that's what's giving the error. Try again without quoting the `sed` script.

Comment: @terdon: Still not able to get that version to work. But, the more general solution provided in "Update" works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This works for your input:

```
sed -Ee's/.*(\{[^}]*(\{[^{}]*\}[^{]*)*\})/\1/'
```

---

```
{foo bar 1}'
{foo bar 2}'
{foo[3]{xyz} bar 3}'
{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 4}'
{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 5}'
{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 6}'
{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 7}'
{foo $sq[3]{xyz}$ bar 8}'
{foo $sq[abc]{xyz}$ bar 9}'
{foo $sq[abc]{xyz}$ bar 10}'
```

It just removes everything before the last occurrence on a line of a matched pair of curlies which might fully contain any number of other matched curly pairs.

Comment: Yep, this too seems to work. It leaves the initial `{` and trailing `}` but that is minor.

Comment: At Peter Grill - drop them. Leave them outside the `(` `)` group: `sed -Ee 's/.*\{([^}]*(\{[^{}]*\}[^{]*)*)\}/\1/'`. Know, though, that it doesn't work to infinite depth. There *isn't* a mathematical equation for that. This selects the last `}` on a line and matches it to its paired `{` so long as that within the `{` and `}` only any number of `{` which are not  followed again by a `{` before a `}` occurs. And so `{ ... { .. } ... { ... } ... { ... } ...}` will match fine, but `{ ... { ... { ... } ... } ... }` will not. You have to specify the depth to which you wish to go, and allow for it.